# readAsDataURL only works when I use a breakpoint on the closing bracket

Tags: jquery, filereader

My function works only when I use a breakpoint on the closing bracket. Where is my mistake? `e` is my model data, which I am getting from a REST API.

```
function onUploadSelectFunction(e){
  if (e.data.myUrl == null) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0].rawFile);
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        console.log("Old Logo" + e.data.itemValue.logo);
        console.log("Read New Logo" + reader.result);
        e.data.itemValue.logo = reader.result;
        console.log("Updated Logo" + reader.result);
    }, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it do when it doesn't work?

Comment: Try and add the load event handler first, before you start reading the data, as the example under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL shows.